# How to do calculate more fields with another row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

One table1 has 8 fields, its like formula

```
code code1 calc1 perc1   calc  code2  calc2  perc2 
 a    aa     *    20%     +     bb      *     10%    
 b    a      *            -     cc      *
 c    b      *    2%      +     dd      *     10%
```

formula is
    c=(2%(20%aa+10%bb-cc))+(10%dd)
   so only i used tis kind of format.

```
 Table2 has 2 fields.

field     value
  aa        50
  bb        20
  cc        10
  dd        20
```

these values should be used in table1 format
    calculation format is like this

```
 a = (aa*20%) + (bb*10%)
 b = (a     ) - (cc    )
 c = (b*2%  ) + (dd*10%)

ex:

 a =(50*20%) + (20*10%)    
 b =(12    ) - (10    )    
 c =(2 *2% ) + (20*10%)

that means 
a = (10)+(2)
b = (12)-(10)
c = (0.04)+(2)


I need return answer is '2.04'.
did u understand my task.
How do I do it?
```

Comment: sorry , then you mean, the first operand is always the result of previous?

Comment: S... DO U KNOW HOW TO DO IT...?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the version of Wernfried's into my answer, still credits goes to him!

Comment: btw, please turn off CAPS while commenting, as it means shouting, though you don't mean it purposely.

Comment: ok, sure. just i know about the caps.

Comment: i changed my question, give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting position is really ugly. Try this:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TABLE_TEMP
(
  CODE   VARCHAR2(10),
  formula  VARCHAR2(1000)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

DECLARE
    res NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TABLE_TEMP;
    INSERT INTO TABLE_TEMP 
    SELECT code, CODE1||CALC1||NVL(PERC1, 1)||CALC||CODE2||CALC2||NVL(PERC2, 1)
    FROM TABLE1;

    -- Replace placeholder with code from other lines 
    FOR aLine IN (SELECT code, code1 FROM TABLE1 t ORDER BY code) LOOP
            FOR aExp IN (SELECT code, Formula FROM TABLE_TEMP WHERE code = aLine.CODE1) LOOP
                UPDATE TABLE_TEMP SET Formula = REPLACE(Formula, aExp.code, '('||aExp.Formula||')') WHERE code = aLine.CODE;
            END LOOP;                             
    END LOOP;

    -- Replace placeholder with values
    FOR aLine IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE_TEMP) LOOP
        FOR aExp IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) LOOP
            UPDATE TABLE_TEMP SET Formula = REPLACE(Formula, aExp.field, aExp.VALUE);
        END LOOP;           
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

For the rest you should be able to do according my first answer.

Comment: i have doubt and dont know about your logic. why u r using function?

Comment: It was part of my first idea, I removed it.

Comment: hi, placeholder means what,...?

Answer (score 1):

Table 1 you mentioned as `expression`, and the other table as `code`.

```
select 
exp.No,
exp.Code,
NVL(code1.value,exp.code1) as Code1,
exp.calc,
NVL(code2.value,exp.code2) as Code2,
case 
when exp.calc = '+' then
  NVL(code1.value,exp.code1) + NVL(code2.value,exp.code2)
when exp.calc = '-' then
  NVL(code1.value,exp.code1) - NVL(code2.value,exp.code2)
when exp.calc = '*' then
  NVL(code1.value,exp.code1) * NVL(code2.value,exp.code2)
when exp.calc = '/' then
  NVL(code1.value,exp.code1) / NVL(code2.value,exp.code2)
end as result
from expression exp, code code1, code code2
where exp.code1=code1.filed(+)
  and exp.code2=code2.filed(+);
```

Expanding Werfried's Answer:

```
DECLARE
    Formula VARCHAR2(100);
    res NUMBER;
    isFirst BOOLEAN := TRUE;
    code1 VARCHAr2(10);
    code2 VARCHAr2(10);
    calc VARCHAr2(1);
BEGIN
    FOR aCode IN (SELECT NO, code, code1,calc,code2 FROM table_a ORDER BY NO) LOOP
        code1 := NULL;
        code2 := NULl;
        calc  := NULL;
        FOR aExp IN (SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE filed in (to_char(aCode.code1),to_char(aCode.code2))) LOOP
            IF(code1 is NULL and aCode.code1 = aExp.filed)
            THEN
               IF(isFirst = TRUE) THEN
                  code1 := aExp.value;
                  isFirst := FALSE;
               ELSE
                  code1 := res;
               END IF;
            END IF;

            IF(code2 is NULL AND aCode.code2 = aExp.filed)
            THEN
                code2 := aExp.value;
            END IF;

            calc := aCode.calc;

            if(code1 is NOT NULL AND code2 is NOT NULL) THEN
             EXIT;
            end if;

        END LOOP;
        Formula := NVL(code1,res)||calc||NVL(code2,aCode.code2);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin :res := '||Formula||';end;' USING OUT res;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( aCode.NO ||': '|| Formula || ' = ' || res);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: u didnt put value in tis...!

Comment: Oops, now I did. Thanks!

Comment: hi, i changed the question, refer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  NO NUMBER,
  code NUMBER,
  code1 VARCHAR2(10),
  calc VARCHAR2(10),
  code2 VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  filed VARCHAR2(10),
  VALUE NUMBER);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1,1, 'a', '+', 'b');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (2,3, '1', '-', 'c');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (3,3, '2', '+', 'd');

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('a', 20);
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('b', 10);
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('c', 10);
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('d', 50);


DECLARE
    Formula VARCHAR2(100);
    res NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR aCode IN (SELECT NO, code, code1||calc||code2 AS Formula FROM table_a) LOOP
        Formula := aCode.Formula;
        FOR aExp IN (SELECT * FROM table_b) LOOP
            Formula := REPLACE(Formula, aExp.filed, aExp.VALUE);
        END LOOP;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin :res := '||Formula||';end;' USING OUT res;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( aCode.NO ||': '|| Formula || ' = ' || res);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Output would be this one:

```
1: 20+10 = 30
2: 1-10 = -9
3: 2+50 = 52
```

In case you need the result from SELECT, you can create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EVAL_FORMULA(Formula IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS
   res NUMBER;
    v_Formula VARCHAR2(100) := Formula;
BEGIN
    FOR aExp IN (SELECT * FROM table_b) LOOP
        v_Formula := REPLACE(v_Formula, aExp.filed, aExp.VALUE);
    END LOOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin :res := '||v_Formula||';end;' USING OUT res;
    RETURN res;
END;

SELECT NO, code, EVAL_FORMULA(code1||calc||code2) AS result
FROM table_a;
```

Comment: Is there a reason to unaccept my answer without putting any comment?

Comment: SORRY, ITS TOO GUD, BUT IT WILL NOT CALCULATE NEXT ROW...! PLEASE TEL ME.

Comment: PLEASE TEL AS SOON AS POSSIBLE. UR RESULT WIL CALCULATE SINGLE ROW ONLY,.

Comment: Waht do you mean? I made an update, is this more what you desire?

Comment: DID U SEE QUST AGAIN...?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I have to do other stuff. I though based on my answer you should be able to extend the function. BTW, your caps-lock key is broken!

Comment: hi, can you help me for my task.

Comment: I don't know how generic the solution should be. Values in column `code1`: Do they refer to `code` or `No`? Which columns are unique?   Can column `code2` contain referrences to `code` or `No`?